# Error: javaweb java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Tags: java

I can find `FileItemFactory`, but when I run it it shows an error.

My project is in java-web. I found the answer to this question is to write xml in pom.xml, but this is java-web so I could not find pom.xml.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVUgy.png)

Comment: How are you running this project? pom.xml is only needed to build with maven. Using a tool like maven would be highly recommended for dependency resolution and portability but it's not strictly necessary. Since this is a java-web project the ultimate goal is to get commons-fileupload.jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web project. Many ways to do that depending on how you are "running" the project.

Comment: just as previous commenter, just because you find the file, does mean that your program finds the file when it runs (runtime). This is where you usually use maven or gradle to define how your application should be built so that when you run it, every class has been bundled up with your program. So how do your run your program?